# Can I replace a 1N4148 diode with a 1N4007?

Tags: diodes

My PC game controller broke and since I have some old PS1 controllers I was thinking about converting one to PC. After some googling I found all I need is a parallel port plug and some 1N4148 diodes. But I live in a small town in the mountains and is not easy for me to get new components, I was wondering if the 1N4007 diodes I have could replace the 1N4148.

> Reference: http://pinouts.ru/Game/playstation_9_pinout.shtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1N4007 is physically bigger and designed for higher current and voltage loads than the 1N4148, but in this case it should be a suitable replacement.

Comment: The 1N4007 is also approximately **1000 times** slower, so in many applications it is an unsuitable replacement for a fast switching diode such as the 1N4148. In this case, as timorr says, it should be okay.

Answer (score 1):

Though both are just normal diodes, they are meant for totally different purposes. You should check the datasheet of both.

IN4148 : http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/1N4148_1N4448.pdf

IN4007 : http://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/329387/CHENG-YI/IN4007/383/1/IN4007.html

Especially for,

1. Maximum Forward current
2. Maximum Forward Voltage drop
3. Switching speed (applicable when data transfers involved, sometimes schottky diodes preferred for this)
4. Maximum Reverse voltage.

With respect to above important characteristics of diodes you can notice from the datasheets that both IN4007 & IN4148 have no near match values.

However, for the purpose of these diodes' interchangeability in your case, the parameter to be considered is the Maximum forward voltage, which is 1.1V for IN4007 (at 1A current, which will not happen with your system). The link you shared says VCC of your play station can vary from 5V down to 3V.

So, your play station should work fine with IN4007.

Answer (score 0):

of course you can replace the IN4148 by IN4007 in emergency case.
check this link:

http://www.trr-jx.com/en/newsDetails_00013.html

Comment: Can you elaborate on the answer and make it so I've does not have to depend on the link?

Comment: Hi Joe Paul, welcome to EE.SE! Please note that this question is 3 years old, and your answer does not add any new information compared to the existing answers. Finally, those diodes have many different properties (as explained by your own link), so there is no "of course" about substituting them. It very much depends how the diode in question is used.

Answer (score -1):

They perform same functions but 1n4007 can stand more volts than 1n4148. You can use 1n4007 in any circuit whether low or high

Comment: They don't perform the same functions.  The 1N400x series are rectifiers, and very slow.  The 1N4148 is a switching diode.  In many environments they absolutely cannot be substituted for each other.